# Ajax in Tinybox 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a [Tinybox 2](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/) popup opening when clicking 'register'. The user has then to choose if he/she wants to register as a user or a performer. I'd like to show a different registration page for each, but first asking it, so handling with ajax would be the best. It can be done, as shown [here](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/), in the 5th example. Here is my current code:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
<head>
<title>Regisztrációs típus kiválasztása</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/soon.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="teljes">
<h1>Miként szeretnél regisztrálni?</h1>
<div id="felhasznalo">
    <a href="#felhaszlano_regisztracio" id="felireg">Felhasználóként</a>
</div>
<div id="eloado">
    <a href="../php/register_performer.php">Előadóként</a>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#felireg').click(function() {
        $.get("../php/register.php");
    });
</script>
</body>
    </html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to make an ajax call to your registration file named "register.php" and show this in a Tinybox

```
$('#felireg').click(function() {
     TINY.box.show({ 
          url:'../php/register.php',width:300,height:150
     })  
});
```

This should work.

//EDIT :
Assuming your file returns only html:

```
$('#felireg').click(function() {
    $.get("../php/register.php", function(data)
    {
         TINY.box.fill(data);
    });
});
```

This should update the current Tinybox

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. You can check it out at www.eroticplaza.hu and click on 'regisztráció'. Don't worry, on this page there is no adult content.